# ADB2C How to share user token between two different applications?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

**I would like to achieve this:**
I have two applications using adb2c for authentication. I would like a user to be able to sign in interactively in the first application and then be logged in silently in the second application.

**What I have for now:**
Both applications are registered in Azure environment, with two different client id.
Both applications share the exact same code, same cache and same configuration, except for the client id.
I am coding in C# and using the Microsoft.Identity.Client dll .

**My issue is:**
If I use the same client id for both applications (as if they were registered as a single application), the user can sign interactively in one application and then be logged in silently in the second one.

But, if I use two different client id, it is no longer working. If the user first signed in interactively in application 1, when I call GetAccountsAsync() in application 2 to get the user account in cache, it returns no account.

**My code:**
To acquire token interactively:

```
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync()
{
   try
   {
      AuthenticationResult ar = await pubClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(config.ApiScopes).WithB2CAuthority(config.GetAuthoritySignUpSignIn()).WithExtraQueryParameters(ui_locale).ExecuteAsync();
      return ar;
   }
   catch (MsalException ex)
   {
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
   return null;
}
```

To acquire token silently:

```
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenSilentAsync()
{
   try
   {
      var accounts = await pubClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
      if (accounts.Count() > 0)
      {
         AuthenticationResult ar = await pubClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(config.ApiScopes,accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
         return ar;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
   return null;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share tokens between the apps, what your observe is expected.

You have to acquire a token interactively on the second app once a silent call fails, and the interactive flow will rely on AAD B2C session cookies to give the user Single Sign On.

You can read about sessions and single sign on here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I read the documentation and I saw this: _"Single sign-on configuration - The Azure AD B2C session can be configured with the following scopes:

Tenant - This setting is the default. Using this setting allows multiple applications and user flows in your B2C tenant to share the same user session. **For example, once a user signs into an application, the user can also seamlessly sign into another one upon accessing it**."_ I am using the Tenant configuration, so according to the documentation what I am trying to achieve should be possible, shouldn't it ?

Comment: It is, as per my answer, you attempt to obtain a token on App 2 from cache, it will fail, then attempt to obtain it interactively, the user will get SSO through browser cookies, and B2C will issue new tokens to App 2. You dont need to configure anything as per the doc for this scenario, only that is expected for App 2 to do a redirect via our authentication endpoint to get SSO.